# jquery - separate JSON and HTML from AJAX Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a AJAX response something like this.

```
[{"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11‌​464"}]<table id="table"></table>
```

It has both JSON and HTML in the response.

I wanted to separate those two things.

And use the JSON for a chart function I've created.

And then append that table to a `div`.

Any suggestions will be very much fruitful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the `HTML` to the `JSON` response.

Comment: It's at the end of the JSON. It's combined.

Comment: Can you change what JSON is returned?

Comment: Change in the sense? Please make it clear. I'm a newbie to these stuffs. Not that expert actually.

Comment: @UnknownUser maybe my answer can help you out doing what you want pretty quickly ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In php**

```
$array = 'Your json array';
$html = 'Your html codes';
```

## Make a single array with two keys

```
$newArray = array();

$newArray['json'] = $array;
$newArray['html'] = $html;

echo json_encode($newArray);
```

**In Jquery**

```
DataType: 'JSON',
success:function(response){

response.json = 'This is your json';
response.html = 'This is your html';
```

}

Comment: It did help me out. I can append the `html`. But when I print the JSON I get as [Object][Object]. And that's causing error for the chart. I need to google on how to convert object to array. Help me if you can and thanks a lot for the response. +1 :)

Comment: I get this output `{"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11‌​464"}`. It is not enclosed by square brackets and this is not being recognised as a JSON data in the chart.

Comment: what type of array are u passing to the json_encode();

Comment: 1st one is a result of database query. 2nd HTML is passing that data to HTML table. Now I manually enclosed that data with `[]` this. And it did work. But I want that to done using jquery itself. Not by concatenating.

Comment: How can I convert this `{"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11‌​464"}` to a JSON data like this `[{"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11‌​464"}]`?

Comment: resource(4) of type (pgsql result) I got this. The link you gave is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `HTML` to the `JSON` response and use it like you would your other values (make sure to escape your html). Also use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to make sure your `JSON` is valid.

```
[
    {
        "label": "label",
        "label1": "67041",
        "label2": "745",
        "label3": "45191",
        "label4": "11‌​464",
        "html": "<table id=\"table\"></table>"
    }
]
```

Comment: I don't know how to separate it. Can you say me?

Comment: @UnknownUser To get the `html` key from this response you would do `response[0].html` [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kyleNeedham/5vR7C/)

Comment: How can I convert this {"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11‌‌​​464"} to a JSON data like this [{"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11‌​‌​464"}]?

Answer (score 0):

While I recommend you not to do that, because is to geeky and hard to maintain, You can solve id by detecting the JSON object using regex, like this:

```
var data = '[{"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11‌464"}]<table  id="table"></table>';

var json_pattr = /\[.*\]/g;
var json_str = json_pattr.exec(data)[0];
var json_data = eval( '(' + json_str.substr(1, json_str.length-2) + ')') ;

var html_pattr = /\}\].*/g;
var html_text = html_pattr.exec(data)[0];
var html_data = html_text.substr(2);

//json_data = [object]   {"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11‌464"}
//html_data = [text] <table id="table"></table>
```

The Best Solution would be to use a template engine like jquery templates to define your html, and then get your data via $.json and evaluate it agains your desired template already on the client, no need to be sending it right along with your data and be doing that kind of processing in run time.

**JavaScript**

```
// assuming you keep receiving this
var data = 
   '[{"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11‌464"},'
  +'{"label":"label2","label1":"0000","label2":"222","label3":"333","label4":"11‌333"}]'
  +'<table id="table"></table>';

// parse the data with regex
var json_pattr = /\[.*\]/g;
var json_str = json_pattr.exec(data)[0];
var json_data = eval( '(' + json_str + ')') ;

var html_pattr = /\}\].*/g;
var html_text = html_pattr.exec(data)[0];
var html_data = html_text.substr(2);

//json_data = [object] {"label":"label","label1": ...
//html_data = [text] <table id="table"></table>   ...

// then use jquery templates to render it
var data = json_data;
$('body').append(html_data);
$('#trTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('#table');
```

**HTML**

```
<script id="trTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
   <tr>
        <td>${label}</td>
        <td>${label1}</td>
        <td>${label2}</td>
        <td>${label3}</td>
        <td>${label4}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#table, td{ border:1px solid #000; padding:5px; }
```

Here is an working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZ8KL/2/) example for you to test it.

Note how this works when you have more than one {json object, it's creates more lines in the table :) }

If you use jquery templates only, and now assuming that you can actually modify your output than the best thing to do is:

**New JavaScript Version of Code with template only and no HTML on 'data'**

```
$.json('http://server.com/url/service/someservice.something', function(data){
    $('body').append(<table id="#table></table>");
    $('#trTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('#table'); 
})
```

Much more simple don't you think?! Hope this helps guiding you on the right path.

Link to jquery tmpl: http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/jquery.tmpl.min.js.

Although after understanding my example, if you are building a system to scale on, and you are not just doing a simple widget app, I would recommend you to check something more robust in terms of functionalities and support like [Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/index.html) as jquery tmpl has been deprecated, unfortunately.